# Считывание полинома из файла C++

Tags: c++, файлы, классы

Возникла проблема при считывании полинома из файла.
Вот непосредственно класс полинома.

```
class Polynomial {
private:
    int deg;//Степень многочлена
    double *Koef;//Массив коэффициентов
public:
    Polynomial();
    Polynomial(int ndeg, double *koef);
    Polynomial(char* fname);//передаем в параметрах имя файла
    ~Polynomial();
    Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial &P);
    Polynomial operator=(const Polynomial &P);
    Polynomial operator/(Polynomial &P);
    Polynomial operator%(Polynomial &P);
    double operator() (const double var);
    int GetDeg();
    double getKoefidx(int index);
};
```

Вот функция считывания из файла

```
Polynomial::Polynomial(char* fname) {
    ifstream ifile(fname);
    char buff[50];
    ifile.getline(buff, 10);//На первой строке переменная dig, на второй - коэффициенты
    char * stde;
    int ndeg = strtol(buff, NULL, 10);
    deg = ndeg;
    Koef = new double[deg + 1];
    ifile.getline(buff, 50);
    char* nch = "";
    int k = 0;
    while (k != deg) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            if (buff[i] != ' ' || buff[i] != '\n' || buff[i] != '\0') 
                nch += buff[i];
            else break;
        }
        Koef[k] = strtod(nch, &stde);
        nch = "";
        k++;
    }
}
```

Пытался выводить все что можно, на что ответом была тишина. Имя файла передаю с расширением, все как положено и оно передается без всяких проблем. Сам файл в директории лежит, но в итоге ничего не происходит. Никаких ошибок, предупреждений и прочего - он просто не передает данные из файла даже в буфер.

Comment: В строке `nch += buff[i];` вы пытаетесь прибавить `char` к указателю. Используйте везде `::std::string` вместо `char *`.

Comment: @VTT Проблема в том, что `getline()` использует в качестве параметров как раз `char`. Если только нет альтернативных функций считывания строки. Да и даже просто при попытке вывести `buff` после передачи в него строки, мне выводит замечательное ничего.

Comment: @ИгорьКуликов, [Все есть](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

Comment: Попробуйте после создания `ifile` написать `if(!ifile) std::cout << "Что-то пошло не так\n";`, и отпишите что получилось

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb насчет `getline()`, не задумывался о таком применении. Наверное, зря. Я его использую непосредственно как `ifile.getline(char*, size)` т.е. так, как написано [тут](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/). Ну и да, вывело, что он не открыл файл. И я не осознаю отчего же, ибо в других программах это работало...

Comment: @ИгорьКуликов, Очевидно проблемы в коде нет. Она либо в имени файла, либо в правах доступа к файлу, либо еще в чем-нибудь. Попробуйте захардкодить имя файла, попробуйте указать абсолютный путь, попробуйте создать новый файл. Короче, экспериментируйте

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb решение с абсолютным путем помогло, спасибо

Comment: @ИгорьКуликов, не ожидал, если честно :) Просто перечислил все что пришло на ум

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло использование абсолютного пути к файлу